# Virt-Manager shared folder Linux host Windows guest

Tags: kvm-virtualization, directory

I have a Manjaro Linux up-to-date host with a KVM Windows 10 guest with SPICE guest additions installed managed through Virt-Manager.
I'd like to be able to access the host via a shared folder on the host.
Virt-Manager has an option just for that, however I configured that option and yet I still can't access the share.
[KVM shared folder settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l608V.png)

What could I still be missing here? Am I missing some other setting on the host? Am I missing some setting on the guest?
Why do I see so many articles talking about SMB shares? I guess (in the background) this shared folder setting could actually be an SMB share but it doesn't make any sense that after setting it up in Virt-Manager I would still need to fiddle with the SMB daemon settings.
Could someone shed some light on the subject, please?
Thank you very much in advance.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to share a Linux filesystem directly to a Windows Guest.
The I/O access is completely different and such a feature would require a complete translation from an NTFS emulation to a disk (D:\ ...) then to an XFS/EXT4/... mapped filesystem. They are not feature agnostic.

The shared folder is intended for mapping a Linux filesystem to a Linux guest through the guest agent.

Comment: Oh...Is that so? That's a real bummer...  
Thanks a bunch, @Bruno Mairlot .
I this can be ironed out in the future by the developers as the software matures and other features land in the code which might help in this case.  
Would you know a good easy way to work around this issue? I tried WinSCP'ing the host from the guest but it failed even though the host is ping'able.  
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may actually be super soon possible. If you use [QEMU 5.0](http://blog.vmsplice.net/2020/04/virtio-fs-has-landed-in-qemu-50.html), with [kernel 5.4](https://libvirt.org/kbase/virtiofs.html) and the [next version](https://github.com/virtio-win/kvm-guest-drivers-windows/issues/126#issuecomment-607611827) of virtio-win, [virtio-fs](https://lwn.net/Articles/774495/) should get you even near-native performance.

Comment: @mirh I'm interested, has there been any progress since ?

Comment: Of course it is possible. VirtualBox can do this very easy.